# Javascript needs to prevent blanks from being entered

Tags: javascript

The following Javascript is attached to a field form (on change ) it is supposed to ensure that if the user clicks on a button then 'off site' will populate in activity_type. And if not then '95 Modifier' will appear. In addition this form sheet has a field I have checked 'required' yet what is happening is the user is able to enter blanks for activity type. Is there a way within this javascript to then not allow a blank to be entered?

```
    if (getFormElement('activity_type_id').toUpperCase()=='EE641670-8BE3-49FD-8914-030740D9DE72' 
&& getFormElement('actual_location').toUpperCase()!='5E74C25C-6363-46BE-B030-16216B364F5A')
    {
    setFormElement('is_off_site',true);
    
    } else 
    {
        setFormElement('is_off_site',false);
    }
    {
        setFormElement('is_off_site',false);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean space?

Comment: first remove extra {  setFormElement('is_off_site',false);   } from your code.

Comment: yes, what is happening is that activity_type is allowed to be entered as spaces. I would want to know if in JS we can prevent this. Via default is ok.

Comment: Is it okay to check via custom function? means when you blank means blank space right?

Comment: not sure see this is a part of an application called Netsmart myevolv and we are given their forms but have can do javascript.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement custom function might solve your issue. It might cover almost your all primary scenarios. I have tried my best to update an answer with the best possibilities.

Please review it.

```js
function isEmpty(inputValue) {
  if(typeof inputValue === 'string' && (inputValue === '0' || inputValue === 'false' || inputValue === '[]' || inputValue === '{}' || inputValue === '')){
    return true;
  }else if(Array.isArray(inputValue)  === true){    
    return inputValue.length === 0 ? true : false;
  }else if(Array.isArray(inputValue) === false && (typeof inputValue === 'object' && inputValue !== null) && typeof inputValue !== 'undefined' && typeof inputValue !== null){
    return Object.keys(inputValue).length === 0 ? true : false;
  }else if(typeof inputValue === 'undefined'){
    return true;
  }else if(inputValue === null){
    return true;
  }else if(typeof inputValue === 'number' && inputValue === 0){
    return true;  
  }else if(inputValue === false){
    return true;  
  }else if(inputValue.length > 0 && inputValue.trim().length === 0){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log("isEmpty(' '): ",isEmpty(' '));
console.log("isEmpty(''): ",isEmpty(''));
console.log("isEmpty([]): ",isEmpty([]));
console.log("isEmpty({}): ",isEmpty({}));
console.log("isEmpty(): ",isEmpty());
const nullValue = null;
console.log("isEmpty(null): ",isEmpty(nullValue));
console.log("isEmpty(0): ",isEmpty(0));
console.log("isEmpty(false): ",isEmpty(false));
console.log("isEmpty('0'): ",isEmpty('0'));
console.log("isEmpty('false'): ",isEmpty('false'));
console.log("isEmpty('[]'): ",isEmpty('[]'));
console.log("isEmpty('{}') ",isEmpty('{}'));
console.log("isEmpty(''): ",isEmpty(''));
console.log("isEmpty('0.0'): ",isEmpty(0.0));
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and `if(inputValue?.length)`?

Comment: It is turnery oprerator, I guess when input value  is not null then only it goes for length function .

Comment: HI Dipak, it is still allowing the activity_type to be saved with spaces.

Comment: @uipathjava can you show your current snippet?